# how to create a chat application using MERN or any other simple way?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io, mern

how to create a chatting application between two person?
for example there is a website with 'n' number of producers, a consumer wants to chat with a particular producer.

how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need tutorials,you can check out `udemy`
https://www.udemy.com/course/socketio-with-websockets-the-details/
,check out the above course for building Chat application with MERN and clustering etc.

Answer (score 0):

Goto [Socket IO](https://socket.io/) official have some easy example to create chat i.e. Peer to Peer chat

Comment: Is there any particualr resource for P2P? like tutorials etc??

Comment: checkout this official doc 
   https://socket.io/blog/socket-io-p2p/ of P2P